# What are the "scalar fields" and "composite fields" in JAVA?

Tags: java, data-structures, data-types, protobuf

Need to understand the below definition, from the [protobuf tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial):

> mergeFrom(Message other): (builder only) merges the contents of other into this message, overwriting **singular scalar fields**, merging **composite fields**, and concatenating repeated fields.

Based on the answers found [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238033/what-does-it-mean-when-data-is-scalar), I could assume that:

**Question 1:**

- A. String *is* a scalar field, since it's not an array.

OR

- B. String *is-not* a scalar field, since it's (like) an array of chars!

So, I would want to have clarity on *what are the EXACT scalar and composite fields* in JAVA? And why?

**Question 2:**

I assume Object to be of 'composite type'. If that's the case, how would objects be merged, in Protobuf?

If Object is *not* a 'composite type', *why?*, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms 'scalar type' or 'scalar field' are usually used to contrast them with compound types/fields. A compound type is easiest to define and it is a type that contains multiple distinct elements. These elements can have the same type, in which case the compound is an array or a list, or different types, in which case the compound is typically a struct or a class. 
A scalar type is a type that contains only a single element.

The set of scalar types contains at least the primitive types, but it might also contain String types, depending on how the community looks at those types. Typically, if a language (or specification like Protocol Buffers) contains a distinct type for storing string data, as opposed to storing strings as an array of characters, then those string types are considered to be scalar types.

---

To understand the `mergeFrom` function, you don't need to know what Java considers to be scalars or compound fields, but what Protocol Buffers considers to be scalar or compound.

The list of scalar types in Protocol Buffers is listed [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar). It consists of primitive types (floating point, integers, booleans, etc.) and string types.
Compound types correspond to the (user-defined) Messages within Protocol Buffers.
Enumeration types may be an odd-one out here. They are formally documented as compound types, but my guess is that the merging semantics are likely to be closer to that of scalar types.

As the `java.Object` class does not have a meaning within the context of Protocol Buffers, it also makes no sense of talking about merging it. The behaviour of the function also appears to only be defined when merging two messages of the same type.

Comment: Your statement `"The list of scalar types in Protocol Buffers is listed here. It consists of primitive types (floating point, integers, booleans, etc.), string and enumeration types."` - means that,  enumerations - is of 'scalar type'. But, based on the protobuf documentation you've provided, `"you can also specify composite types for your fields, including enumerations and other message types."`,  enumerations - is of 'composite types'. You may want to edit your answer, accordingly.

Comment: @RafiAlhamd: I updated my answer. I initially characterized enumerations as scalars based on their underlying implementation details and how they are likely to be merged. Made that more explicit now.

Answer (score 2):

> So, I would want to have clarity on what are the EXACT scalar and composite fields in JAVA? And why?

It's strictly to do with the types defined in a `.proto` file. Java the language doesn't define the meaning here.

Anything you have defined an `enum` or `message` for is composite. The built-in types are scalar.

Elements that are defined `required` or `optional` are singular, those that are `repeated` are repeated.

> I assume Object to be of 'composite type'. If that's the case, how would objects be merged, in Protobuf?

`java.lang.Object` isn't a type in Protobuf. It isn't present to be merged.

> If Object is not a 'composite type', why?, then?

Protobuf can only operate on things it has descriptions for. Remember there is a `.proto` -> `.java` compile step.